# Wiping a cell with dynamic data validation *without* VBA

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I've been asked to "fix" a spreadsheet that has two interacting columns with data validation; one, "Cargo Class", that validates from a list consisting of **Auto**, **HighHeavy** and **Breakbulk**, and one, "Cargo Segment", that validates from one of three lists determined by an `INDIRECT` function.

It all works fine initially, but if the user selects a cargo segment based on a chosen cargo class and then changes the cargo class, it will end up with an invalid combination of segment and class.

I initially fixed this by adding a `Worksheet.Change` event as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Row > 21 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).ClearContents
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

And that works fine, *if* the users remember to enable macros. If they haven't, of course, it makes no difference.

I then looked at a few different solutions, most notably the one at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/#prevent-changes-primary-dropdown to block changes, but apparently that would confuse people even more than asking them to enable content.

Is there any way I can clear Cargo Segment using only formulas or data validation when Cargo Class is changed, without using VBA and without locking Cargo Class completely?

Comment: If it can't be acheived with an `=IF()` forumla as part of your validation, then no - nothing else can affect other cells in the workbook apart from VBA procedures without user interaction.

Comment: It's not quite as tricky to circumvent as the automatic clearing, but I made the fields turn bright red with the rule `=OR(AND(COUNTIF(Auto, $E22), NOT($D22="Auto")), AND(COUNTIF(HighHeavy, $E22), NOT($D22="HighHeavy")), AND(COUNTIF(Breakbulk, $E22), NOT($D22="Breakbulk")))`. So now it'll automatically clear the Segment field if VBA is enabled, and flag it nice and bright if it isn't. I use conditional formatting all the time, but using it here just never occurred to me. Thanks, @pnuts!

Comment: If you want to add your suggestion as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @pnuts' idea, I kept the auto-clearing VBA script, but added some conditionals to highlight invalid combinations in bright red, using this rule:

```
=OR(AND(COUNTIF(Auto, $E22), NOT($D22="Auto")), AND(COUNTIF(HighHeavy, $E22), NOT($D22="HighHeavy")), AND(COUNTIF(Breakbulk, $E22), NOT($D22="Breakbulk")))
```

...where `Auto`, `HighHeavy` and `Breakbulk` are lists of the cargo segments used to populate column `E`, and column `D` contains the cargo class.

So now if macros are enabled the segment field is blanked if an invalid class is selected, and if macros aren't enabled it'll flag incorrect combinations in a fairly unmissable way. Thanks, folks!